# How to attach variables to the Graphql context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I am using express-graphql.
I want to attach some params to the context, but they don't attach.

Middlware:

```
  app.use(graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: resolver,
  graphiql: true,
  context: {someValue: 100}
}))
```

Schema:

```
type Query {
  get_number: Int!
}
```

Resolver:

```
get_number(_, __, context) {
 console.log(context);
 return context.someValue;
}
```

When I try to call get_number it says:

```
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.get_number.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 2
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "get_number"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Here's what console.log(context) says:

```
{
  fieldName: 'get_number',
  fieldNodes: [
    {
      kind: 'Field',
      alias: undefined,
      name: [Object],
      arguments: [],
      directives: [],
      selectionSet: undefined,
      loc: [Object]
    }
  ],
  returnType: Int!,
  parentType: Query,
  path: { prev: undefined, key: 'get_number' },
  schema: GraphQLSchema {
    __validationErrors: [],
    __allowedLegacyNames: [],
    _queryType: Query,
    _mutationType: Mutation,
    _subscriptionType: undefined,
    _directives: [ @skip, @include, @deprecated ],
    astNode: undefined,
    extensionASTNodes: undefined,
    _typeMap: [Object: null prototype] {
      Query: Query,
      TestType: TestType,
      Int: Int,
      User: User,
      String: String,
      Float: Float,
      ClassMatein: ClassMatein,
      ClassMate: ClassMate,
      Mutation: Mutation,
      UserInput: UserInput,
      __Schema: __Schema,
      __Type: __Type,
      __TypeKind: __TypeKind,
      Boolean: Boolean,
      __Field: __Field,
      __InputValue: __InputValue,
      __EnumValue: __EnumValue,
      __Directive: __Directive,
      __DirectiveLocation: __DirectiveLocation
    },
    _possibleTypeMap: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _implementations: [Object: null prototype] {}
  },
  fragments: [Object: null prototype] {},
  rootValue: {
    test: [Function: test],
    random: [Function: random],
    addTestUser: [Function: addTestUser],
    get_mate: [Function: get_mate],
    get_number: [Function: get_number]
  },
  operation: {
    kind: 'OperationDefinition',
    operation: 'query',
    name: undefined,
    variableDefinitions: [],
    directives: [],
    selectionSet: { kind: 'SelectionSet', selections: [Array], loc: [Object] },
    loc: { start: 0, end: 21 }
  },
  variableValues: {}
}
```

My schema:

```
const {
  buildSchema
} = require('graphql')
const gql = require('graphql-tag');

module.exports = buildSchema(`
  type User {
    name: String!
    email: String!
    age: Int!
  }
```

I guess my someValue should be in variableValues, but it's not there:(
What should I do to attach this variable(someValue) to the context?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify "they don't attach"? You mean the code as-is does not work? Does it throw an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: That looks like it should work. What output do you get from the  `console.log`?

Comment: @Bergi I've added the output and logged context. Can you please take a look:)

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've added some more info about my problem. Can you please take a look:)

Comment: It looks like your actual code is logging the fourth argument (`resolveInfo`), not the third (`context`).

Comment: @Bergi I am not using an Apollo server, I am just using:
 `async function start() {
  try {
    // await sequelize.sync()
    app.listen(PORT)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}`
So in my case context is in the second paramer (__), so parent doesn't exist in express-graphql or I get something wrong?
Can you, please, help me if you know, how can I fix this issue?:)

Comment: How do you create `schema`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing your `resolvers` object as the `rootValue`. Instead, you should put them in your schema, e.g. using `makeExecutableSchema`.

A resolver takes four arguments: parent object, field arguments, context, and resolve info.

If there is no resolver for a field in the schema, GraphQL falls back to simply accessing the property with the field name on the parent object (which is the `rootValue` for fields on the root `Query` type). If the property is a method, it invokes the method (i.e. `this` = parent object) with three arguments: field arguments, context , and resolve info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are amazing:)